# Can I access the Flash security manager without an Internet connection?

Tags: security, settings, flash, offline-mode

When Flash Player 10 thought that I was doing an "unsafe operation", it told me that to reset security settings I have to go online, somewhere around this link http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager.html .

Well, great, except what if (hypothetically) it's difficult to get Internet connection? Is there a way to do the security and other settings for Flash while offline?

Answer (score 0):

Good question. I don't *think* they offer such a mechanism.  You could probably "cheat" and use Fiddler to capture the traffic to the page, then use the AutoResponder to reload that traffic and play it back... See video #2 here: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/video/